# Replace an item in a list

Tags: python

I have a list which will add random items in any order. I am looking for a way to replace an item with another item & at the same time keep the same index position, without knowing which index position it will originally be in.

So for example randomly generated list:  `hand = ["A", 3]`. I want to remove/replace `"A"`
Regardless if `"A"` was in Index 0 or 1 & when I re-add `"A"` it will be in the same index position.

And if in the event `hand = ["A", 3, "A"]`. I only want the first `"A"` to be removed/replaced.

```
one = ["A", 3, "A"]

if "A" in one[:2]:
    A = 11
    one.remove("A")
    one.append(A)

if "A" in one[2:]:
    a = 1
    one.remove("A")
    one.append(a)
```

What I've tried so far but this removes an item and adds it to the end of the list. This is the type of concept I am looking for

```
# Randomly generated list
hand = ["A", 3, "A"]
# Convert string to var(Numbers)
hand = [11, 3, 1]
one = sum(hand) 
# Convert hand back to list
hand = ["A", 3, "A"]
```

Comment: You want to replace an item without knowing in which position it is? Try `hand[hand.index('A')] = new_item`

Comment: This works. is there a way to make it so that any `"A"` items past index 1 automatically get replaced rather than having to do it manually?

Comment: Yes, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace all 'A's with a new item:

```
new_item = 'whatever'
hand = ["A", 3, "A"]
hand = [new_item if x == 'A' else x for x in hand]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
a = ["A", 3, "A"]
try:
    # Replace first occurrence of A with B
    a[a.index("A")] = "B"
except ValueError:
    pass
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```py
if 'A' in hand:
    hand[hand.index('A')] = <replacement>
```